Finding partial trace in CIRQ
Suppose I have a 30 qbit system, due to computational complexity, I can't find the density matrix of the system. But is it possible to find the partial trace of the  a sub-system of 2 qubits out of 30 without explicitly finding the density matrix?

you try to create a smaller circuit with only the target qubits, the operation that act on them and the qubit affected by those operations. but depending on your circuit you could end up with the original circuit that may not help unless your circuit doesn't entangle lots of qubits together

How to code in cirq?

@PeterSmith 30 qubits will take longer, suppose I have 5 qubit circuit and need to find the reduced density matrix of the first two qubit, how can I code in cirq?
